# Dynamic GUI Framework Designing

Tags: java, c++, oracle, qt

There is a Scenario to be developed for a 3-tier Application .We need to design a Framework or a utility sort of thing .

In tradional aspect of GUI Designing ,  either we tend to create a static gui page and code the elements on it along with other properties of the elements such as (disabled/enabled,image source,name ,id ,which function to be called under onclick event.) or we tend to drag and drop the elements from the control pallete provided by variety of gui frameworks.

Certain things i need to design a POC so that we can develop this concept.

1. There must a utility ,such that during creation of screen layout , that screen should be saved in the database(RDBMS) with a screen number.
2. All the Events related to that control should be saved in some other table which will be dynamically mapped during the calling of screen number by the user.
3. When the user call that screen ,a generic function  should be invoked which'll call the screen file from the database and apply all the properties ,events,etc at runtime and the final output will be displayed to the user.

This POC will help the us to customised the screens according to our usage.also all the code will seperated which can easily be used for some other development process.

Thanks 
Amit Kalra

*-- Migrated from Answer --*

Iam not getting it with GUI framework supporting serialization .

The Concept should be like this .

1. The Developer has a utility like a Screen Painter in which developer can drag drop controls ,now this file will get saved in 2 formats ,first one is a source file and another on is the compiled one (say compiled in a .cpp format or any other format).
2. now on a client side ,when the user enters any transaction number ,there should be a utility which can load the file from the database ,also apply all the functions applicable to each event .
3. This Concept is similar to wat is there in SAP R/3.

please help me in undergoing this POC.
Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Very similar to [Qt : C++ dynamic parameter GUI for plugin parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655824/qt-c-dynamic-parameter-gui-for-plugin-parameters)

Comment: @user575715 Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have details you would like to add, please do so by editing your original question. I've moved your comments from below into your original question for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you are asking for a GUI framework supporting **serialization**. There are several ones supporting this. Two I have been using are the [FOX Toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/) (C++, cross-platform) and the [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) (.NET), which is using the XAML format for serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the purpose by using the Serialization support of many popular languages. Even if there is no support for that it shouldn't not be very difficult, storing essential data in some configuration files (or as such in your case storing in a DB) will do the expected like controls details, their position etc. But standard frameworks will make your life easy in long running.